# get info from one page and show it on other page

Tags: asp.net

i m working on shopping cart site 
i want to show complete information of a product contained in a div section. on an other page. i have may div that contained information. 
goal is to get the info on a new page when user clicks some product's image.

```
   Error: 
           Control 'MainContent_ImageButton1' of type 'ImageButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
    HTML:
      <div id="physics" runat="server">
        <h3>High School Physics</h3>
      <%--  <a href="ShowLarge.aspx"> <img src="images/Book.jpg" />  </a>--%>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" 
                src="images/Book.jpg" runat="server" onclick="ImageButton1_Click"  />
        <p> Book Description Goes Here
        <br />
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">PKR 770/-</asp:Label>
         <br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" />
        </p>

    </div>

    Code :
     protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        physics.RenderControl(w);
        Session["mySessionVar"]  = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

            Response.Redirect("ShowLarge.aspx", true);

        }

    HTML: where i want to show this info 

    <div id="ShowInLargeView" runat="server">
    </div>

    Code: 

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInLargeView.InnerHtml = (String)Session["mySessionVar"];
        }
```

i want to show the complete info of Div in an other page. i m getting an error. this scenario is about shopping cart 
i need help 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is related to the fact that you are trying to add an event handler

```
   protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
```

In order to add an event handler to an element on your page it will need to be encapsulated in a 'form' with the runat="server" attribute. this will result in the click event of the ImageButton ending up in your code-behind.

so your aspx would become something like :

```
<form runat="server">
      <div id="physics" runat="server">
        <h3>High School Physics</h3>
      <%--  <a href="ShowLarge.aspx"> <img src="images/Book.jpg" />  </a>--%>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" 
                src="images/Book.jpg" runat="server" onclick="ImageButton1_Click"  />
        <p> Book Description Goes Here
        <br />
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">PKR 770/-</asp:Label>
         <br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" />
        </p>

    </div>
</form>
```

In general it should suffice to encapsulate your entire page in a form tag, this way all events will be passed to your code-behind.

Comment: i have total of 5 div tags that are all in one form tag. 
i don't know why this error is coming. as you have said it is already encapsulated in form tag with runat="server"

Comment: Why don't you just implement the shopping cart as a Webcontrol?  
Rendering the the thing to a string and then including that string in another element seems overly complex and error-prone.